# How can I access type members from a trait in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, existential-type

I'm trying to create a type that captures the idea of a pair of related types.

I'd then like to write functions parameterized over the captured types. Unfortunately, I'm unable to correctly express the types and end up with a type mismatch.

I have a strong preference for using type parameters and getting rid of the type members but I'm not sure how else to refer to the type parameters.

Here's my test code

```
class Types {

  trait TypePair[A, B] {
    type FROM = A
    type TO   = B
  }

  class Execute[TP <: TypePair[_, _]](func: TP#FROM => TP#TO) {

    def execute(in: TP#FROM): TP#TO = func(in)

  }

}
```

Here's the error message

```
Error:(12, 44) type mismatch;
 found   : in.type (with underlying type _$1)
 required: _$1
    def execute(in: TP#FROM): TP#TO = func(in)`
```

Comment: What exactly did you tried to model here? What is the use case? Assume this works, how should I use execute? Should I explicitly specify the `TP` type? If so, why? If not, then why this exist at all?

Comment: I'm trying to model pairs of classes that represent request and response message types. The idea is to build up a type-safe library of functions that are available on certain groups of messages.

The eventual goal is to create type classes over TP and make instances of the typeclasses available implicitly. This will define TP through the existence of the type class implicit.

Comment: OK, so the final goal is: 1. that me as an user specify the type pair and the system will infer the function? Or 2. That as an user specifies the function and the system validates that such input-output pair is valid?

Comment: The latter. There are two major goals. The first is to ensure that the correct response type is generated. The second and more important goal is to statically check that only transformations valid for a given message type available. By having transformation functions with context bounds I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough for your first requirement.

```
object Types {
  sealed trait Request

  object Request {
    final case object ARequest extends Request
    final case object BRequest extends Request
  }

  sealed trait Response

  object Response {
    final case object AResponse extends Response
    final case object BResponse extends Response
  }

  trait TypePair[I <: Request, O <: Response]

  object TypePair {
    implicit final val ARequestAResponse: TypePair[Request.ARequest, Response.AResponse] =
      new TypePair[Request.ARequest, Response.AResponse]

    implicit final val BRequestAResponse: TypePair[Request.BRequest, Response.AResponse] =
      new TypePair[Request.BRequest, Response.AResponse]

    implicit final val BRequestBResponse: TypePair[Request.BRequest, Response.BResponse] =
      new TypePair[Request.BRequest, Response.BResponse]
  }

  final class Execute[-I, +O](func: I => O)(implicit ev: TypePair[I, O])  {
    def execute(in: I): O = func(in)
  }
}
```

I do not quite understand your second requirement, so I am not sure if this is enough for what you need. If not, feel free to leave your feedback and edit your question with more ifnormation. Or open a new one if you feel the problem is pretty different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work around this problem if you get rid of type wildcards, for example:

```
class Types {

  trait TypePair[A, B] {
    type FROM = A
    type TO = B
  }

  sealed trait ABType
  case class ABTypeInt() extends ABType
  case class ABTypeString() extends ABType

  class Execute[TP <: TypePair[ABType, ABType]](func: TP#FROM => TP#TO) {

    def execute(in: TP#FROM): TP#TO = func(in)
  }

}
```